# How to reload page after accepting cookies without loading the cookie banner again

Tags: javascript, cookies, web-analytics-tools

we have web analytics added in the project. the current implementation works like: when use accept the cookies and reload the page then only the home page visit gets counted in analytics.

I tried to reload the page after accepting the cookies which is reloading the cookie banner too. After the reload the analytics capture the visit. I want to achive this.